# Load Balance two servers with a Flask app with CertBot certificate and a Domain Name

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, load-balancing, certbot, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two servers, let's call them `ServerA` and `ServerB`.

I bought a domain on NameCheap let's call it `example.com`

Each server has docker containers (Flask Web Apps) running on it on different ports.

Example:

```
WebApp1 running on port 8080
WebApp2 running on port 8081
.
.
```

The configuration is the same across both servers.

I then use nginx for a reverse proxy on port 443 each with their own sub domain.

Example:

```
WebApp1 running on port 8080 will be accessible via test1.example.com
WebApp2 running on port 8081 will be accessible via test2.example.com
.
.
```

I am using CertBot for the SSL certificates.

My two servers are hosted on OCI (Oracle Cloud) and I build a network load balancer on OCI to balance traffic across my servers.

Below are my configs:

`nginx.conf`

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 800;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # General Logging Settings
    ##
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##
    # gzip on;
    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_min_length 10240;
    # gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
    # gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    ##
    # Web Apps configurations
    ##
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test1.example.com`

```
server {
  server_name   test1.example.com;

  location / {
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/test1/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/test1/error.log;
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;
  }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test1.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test1.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = test1.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

  server_name   test1.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Currently, the domain name test1.example.com has an A record to ServerA which is working fine and i can access my WebApp.

But I want the domain to point to my Load Balancer so that i can balance the traffic on both servers. But i can't do that unless i issue SSL certificates on both servers which i can't. Because after issuing test1.example.com on `ServerA`, doing so on `ServerB` results in an error by certbot saying that the certificate has already been assigned to `ServerA`.

Can someone help me out on how i can do that ?

Comment: Only obtain the certificate on one server, and then run a script to copy it over to the second server. Certbot has [pre- and post-renew scripts](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#renewing-certificates) that could be used to help automate that process. Or, if its supported on oracle cloud, store the certificates on a shared volume that's accessible to both servers.